# How to reuse common types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have multiple react components that reuse the same props, and am wondering if there is an easy way for me to store and re-use these typings.

For example:

**before:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface AnotherButtonProps {
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

interface SampleButtonProps {
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  title: string;
}

const AnotherButton: React.FC<AnotherButtonProps> = ({ disabled = false, onClick }) => (
  <button
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={onClick}
    type="button"
  >
    This is another button
  </button>
);

const SampleButton: React.FC<SampleButtonProps> = ({ disabled = false, onClick, title }) => (
  <button
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={onClick}
    type="button"
  >
    {title}
  </button>
);
```

**afer:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Disabled {
  disabled?: boolean;
}

interface OnClick {
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

interface Title {
  title: string;
}

interface AnotherButtonProps {
  disabled?: Disabled;
  onClick: OnClick;
}

interface SampleButtonProps {
  disabled?: Disabled;
  onClick: OnClick;
  title: Title;
}

const AnotherButton: React.FC<AnotherButtonProps> = ({ disabled = false, onClick }) => (
  <button
    disabled={disabled} // get error
    onClick={onClick}
    type="button"
  >
    This is another button
  </button>
);

const SampleButton: React.FC<SampleButtonProps> = ({ disabled = false, onClick, title }) => (
  <button
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={onClick}
    type="button"
  >
    {title}
  </button>
);
```

When I try to reuse these common interfaces, I get the following error:

> TS2322: Type 'boolean | Disabled' is not an assignable type 'boolean'. Type 'Disabled' is not is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use implements

For example:

```
interface SampleButtonProps implements Disabled, OnClick, Title {}
```